# Which is my spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot, maven-dependency

I'm developing a web application with Spring-boot and it's all been working quite well.

I've been editing and testing it on my browser like it's been deployed to a server.

But now I want to generate my war file, and according to [Spring's documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html), I have to mark the tomcat dependecies as *provided*. The thing is that I don't see this dependency anywhere in my pom.xml.

**Question**: Which dependency should I mark as provided?

These are the ones I actually have in my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: what's your spring-boot-starter-parent version in your POM?

Comment: You got the right parent in your answer, I'll test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest parent version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

And running a [dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) on the project:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

To check which declared dependency is bringing in the embedded Tomcat server, you get as part of the output:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile   
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile   
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile   
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.32:compile   
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.32:compile   
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.32:compile   
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.32:compile
```

Which means the declared `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency is bringing it, in particular is bringing `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.3.3.RELEASE` in.

You can esplicitely declared it as [`provided`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) which will then influence as well projects dependencies management and as such the `war` packaging.

Hence, add to you pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note: if your parent version is different, you can apply exactly the same process and spot the undeclared embedded dependency again (which could have a different version), then re-declare it as provided.